# How to display the port numbers of open connections for a specific process with tcpvcon.exe (Windows 10)?

Tags: windows, port, internet-connection

I have both TCPView and Tcpvcon on my Windows 10 machine and I wonder how to get all the information (port numbers, etc.) displayed in TCPView in the output of the Tcpvcon program? TCPView has the process name, PID, protocol, remote address, remote port, etc. in its output to the GUI. Tcpvcon, on the other hand, only contains the process name, protocol, remote and local address. I would like to have all information that can be read in the TCPView GUI in the command line output of Tcpvcon (especially the port numbers). Tcpvcon seems to have only the three switches -a -c -n but no matter how I combine them, I do not reach my goal. Can anyone help me?

Below is a sample output when I use all three switches. In TCPView I see much more information about the specified process.
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also very surprised that tcpvcon does not show port numbers (maybe we should ask Mark R. to add them ;-)

BUT you could use

```
netstat -a -o -n
```

or with an admin shell even

```
netstat -a -o -n -b
```

switches meaning:

```
-a ... Displays all active TCP connections and the TCP and UDP ports 
       on which the computer is listening.

-o ... Displays active TCP connections and includes the process ID (PID)
       for each connection.

-n ... Displays active TCP connections, however, addresses and port numbers 
       are expressed numerically and no attempt is made to determine names.

-b ... Displays the executable involved in creating each connection or 
       listening port. (Note that this option can be time-consuming and 
       will fail unless you have sufficient permissions.)
```

To get all available switches just use **netstat -?** (there are other interesting ones) or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/netstat

swobi

Comment: This does not solve the problem with Tcpvcon but helps me to solve my task. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Up until the 2011 release of TCPVCON, it used to show port info.

The newer versions don't any more.

If you could get your hand on version 2.54, you would be able to get port info.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with tcpvcon-v2.34 (I couldn't find 2.54) and it shows the ports but it doesn't show the process, all conections appear as from System. Also TCPV6 and UDPV6 are missing.

This is an example:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>"C:\My Program Files\TCPView-v4.13\tcpvcon-v2.34.exe" -a -c
TCP,System,-1,LISTENING,WXP-OR7507156:epmap,WXP-OR7507156:0
TCP,System,-1,LISTENING,WXP-OR7507156:microsoft-ds,WXP-OR7507156:0
TCP,System,-1,LISTENING,WXP-OR7507156:sms-rcinfo,WXP-OR7507156:0
TCP,System,-1,LISTENING,WXP-OR7507156:5040,WXP-OR7507156:0
TCP,System,-1,LISTENING,WXP-OR7507156:wsd,WXP-OR7507156:0
..
UDP,System,-1,,192.168.56.1:137,*:*
UDP,System,-1,,192.168.56.1:138,*:*
UDP,System,-1,,192.168.56.1:2177,*:*
UDP,System,-1,,192.168.56.1:5353,*:*
```

EDIT:
I correct myself. ASB was right.
I just got TCPView v2.54 and it does indeed show the application, the ports and also TCPV6 and UDPV6.

So I confirm that the "good" version is v2.54.

```
Tcpvcon.exe -a -c

TCPView v2.54 - TCP/UDP endpoint viewer
Copyright (C) 1998-2009 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

TCP,dnscrypt-proxy.exe,4188,LISTENING,WXP-XXX:domain,WXP-XXX:0
TCP,[System Process],0,TIME_WAIT,WXP-XXX:domain,localhost:62240
..
UDP,Teams.exe,12632,*,WXP-XXX:58950,*:*
TCPV6,svchost.exe,1232,LISTENING,wxp-XXX:135,wxp-XXX:0
..
UDPV6,svchost.exe,19712,*,wxp-XXX:50836,*:*
UDPV6,System,4,*,wxp-XXX:56736,*:*
```

Answer (score -1):

To display the port numbers (and the process names) you need the old v2.54 version of tcpvcon.exe

This SysinternalsSuite.zip Archive from the Wayback Machine contains this version:
https://web.archive.org/web/20100201154325/http://download.sysinternals.com/Files/SysinternalsSuite.zip

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.